# Difference between "Get Xcode" and "Install"

Tags: macos, xcode

I've just upgraded to Yosemite, and I'm getting the following dialog box:

[image: Message asking to choose between Get Xcode and Install]

> **The "cc" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you
>   like to install the tools now?**
>
> Choose Install to continue. Choose Get Xcode to install Xcode and the command line developer tools from the App Store.
>
> <kbd>Get Xcode</kbd><kbd>Not now</kbd><kbd>**Install**</kbd>

What is the difference between the two? In particular, does "Install" have a smaller download size  than the "Get Xcode" option?

Comment: Get Xcode will install the tools + Xcode

Answer (score 2):

Get Xcode installs both the IDE and command line developer tools.

According to apple this is the contents of that package:

> This package enables UNIX-style development via Terminal by installing command line developer tools, as well as Mac OS X SDK frameworks and headers. Many useful tools are included, such as the Apple LLVM compiler, linker, and Make. If you use Xcode, these tools are also embedded within the Xcode IDE.

Source [XCode Command Line Tools - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools)